# How to search through in JSON array on SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-5.6

I'm using MySQL 5.6.43 and trying to search through in JSON array in a table. My JSON in MySQL database is like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "AAA",
        "CountryCode": "AFG",
        "District": "Kabol",
        "Population": 1780000
    },
    {
        "Name": "BBB",
        "CountryCode": "AFG",
        "District": "Qandahar",
        "Population": 237500
    },
    {
        "Name": "CCC",
        "CountryCode": "USD",
        "District": "Qandahar",
        "Population": 237500
    }
]
```

I want to take the just `AFG` `CountryCode`'s. So my result should be like this:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "AAA",
        "CountryCode": "AFG",
        "District": "Kabol",
        "Population": 1780000
    },
    {
        "Name": "BBB",
        "CountryCode": "AFG",
        "District": "Qandahar",
        "Population": 237500
    }
]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Parse the array of objects to separate objects (use JSON_TABLE() function), check each object's property, then aggregate matched objects back.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for your response. Can you explain it via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT test.data, JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT('Name',jsontable.Name,
                                            'CountryCode',jsontable.CountryCode,
                                            'District',jsontable.District,
                                            'Population',jsontable.Population)) filtered
FROM test,
     JSON_TABLE(test.data,
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (Name VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.Name',
                                CountryCode VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.CountryCode',
                                District VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.District',
                                Population VARCHAR(255) PATH '$.Population')) jsontable
WHERE jsontable.CountryCode = 'AFG'
GROUP BY test.data;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a40c87cc3ae466799d57a20938e0519c)

In MySQL 5.6 you must use string functions - JSON is not implemented in this version yet:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT('[', GROUP_CONCAT('{', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test.data, '}', nums.num), '}', -1), '{', -1), '}'), ']') filtered
FROM test
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 num UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4) nums
WHERE LOCATE('"CountryCode":"AFG"', SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REPLACE(test.data, ' ', ''), '}', nums.num), '}', -1))
GROUP BY test.data
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=bd12a08965cd393c88272f3d8be4e130)

If source array may contain more than 4 objects per value then expand `nums` subquery.

Restriction: Neither key nor value to be searched must contain a space.

Comment: Is it valid for MySQL?

Comment: @sundowatch Have you seen the fiddle by link? it is executed in MySQL 8.0.21 successfully. But if the version is ancient then it will not work - JSON_TABLE was implemented in 8.0.4.

Comment: Hmm, ok. I'm using 5.6.43. Is there any equevelant for this?

Comment: @sundowatch For this version you must use common string functions.

Comment: Do you mean `LIKE` or any other common string functions?

Comment: @sundowatch The query for your version added.